# Failed to pass array to child component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-http, angular2-formbuilder

I want the [Dynamic Forms Cookbook example](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/cb-dynamic-form/ts/plnkr.html) to work with http service. The error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` where the `undefined` is regarding array I'm passing to child component.

Feel free to look it into [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KmCXdL?p=preview). I've made a change to original example adding Http service which get data from json file.

What I do wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

questions has to be initialized, and ngOnChanges has to used.
AppComponent

```
this.questions = [];
```

DynamicFormComponent

```
ngOnChanges() {
  this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions);
}
```

See http://embed.plnkr.co/fHXC0T/